# bash test cmd fails with too many args

Tags: bash, testing, puppet

In Puppet provisioning, I do have problems which cause puppet run in every turn. It's masterless configuration using perodic cron job execution.

```
 exec { 'postgresql::server::database::action1':
        command => "sudo -u postgres psql -d ${db_name} -a -f /opt/folderx/v2/createdb.sql",
        path    => '/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin',
        user    => 'root',
        onlyif  => "test $(sudo -u postgres psql -d ${db_name} -c 'SELECT version();' ; echo $?) -ne 0",
    }
```

Question which is correct syntax to onlyif testing ? In bash shell I will get:

> bash: test: too many arguments

Basically I need to test does some tables and functions exist in given $dbame

Answer (score 2):

Does `postrgres psql -d ...` print something to the screen? If yes, then its output is passed on as parameters to `test`. To hide the output you can redirect it using `... > /dev/null`.

The `test $(someCommand; echo $?) -ne 0` is overly complicated, just write `! someCommand`. That way you probably wouldn't have to redirect the output too.

```
onlyif  => "! sudo -u postgres psql -d ${db_name} -c 'SELECT version();' > /dev/null",
```

Comment: In bash and correct postgres syntax yes. But it didn't work with test cmd .. Anyway your code example did help me and puppet will not call exec funcs anymore. I'll make soon reverse testings but seems to work.

Comment: Other solution is run script only when content of a file has been changed ...  `        file { "/opt/folderx/v2/createdb.sql":
            audit => 'content'
        }
`